# How do I import an EPUB e-book into my Kindle?

Tags: kindle, epub

How do I import an EPUB (.epub) e-book into my Kindle considering that file format is not native to Kindle's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out as I had not received an answer:

1. Download the open-source Calibre e-book management software from
   [here](https://calibre-ebook.com/download).
2. Once it's installed, open Calibre and add an EPUB e-book to its
   library by clicking on the "Add books" button.
3. After you have added the e-book to the Calibre library, select it,
   and then click the "Convert books" button.
4. This will open a new window with a few options and formats to
   convert to.
5. Select ".MOBI" for the format.  This is important because .MOBI is
   compatible with Kindle unlike .EPUB.
6. Once you've converted it, you can plugin your Kindle and use Calibre
   to send the .MOBI e-book version to your Kindle so you can read it
   there.

Comment: MOBI format works but you may need to remove the *pdoc* tag so that it shows up on your kindle as a book instead of a personal document. Converting from EPUB to AZW3 is the newer Kindle format and generally works better.

Comment: BookFusion provides an alternative way to seamlessly send your eBooks to your Kindle devices. More details at https://blog.bookfusion.com/how-to-quickly-easily-transfer-ebooks-to-your-kindle/